# How to modify the Actor-Critic policy gradient algorithm to perform Safe exploration in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: actor-critic-methods, exploration-exploitation-tradeoff

I am trying to implement safe exploration technique in [Ref.1]. I am using Soft Actor-Critic algorithm to teach an agent to introduce a bias between 0 and 1 to a specific state of interest in my environment.

**I would like to ask for your help** in order to modify the critic update equation -which is originally  based on the return or the RL cost function- **from this**:

[image]

which is based on the return functions:

[image]  =

[image]

**to be based on the following cost function** to make the RL objective risk-sensitive and avoid large-valued actions (bias values) at the start of the agent's learning,

[image]

**How can I include the second part of the cost function - in which the variance of the reward is evaluated- in the update equation?**

[Ref.1] *Heger, M., Consideration of risk in reinforcement learning. 11th International Machine Learning Conference (1994)*

Comment: what is $c_t$ here?

Comment: It’s the return at instant t. When compared to the $R_t$ equation, $c_t $ ~ $r_{t+k+1}